# Converting int to str in python is producing TypeError

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
a = date.datetime.today().month
b = date.datetime.strptime(str(a) , '%m')
```

This code goes into error because it is expecting a string. variable `a` is `int`. How can i convert into to string. I tried `str(a)` and that did not work.

The error i get is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-80ff451251fc> in <module>
      1 a = date.datetime.today().month
----> 2 b = date.datetime.strptime(str(a) , '%m')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: `str(a)` should do that. Post the full traceback.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the full traceback to the question

Comment: The problem is that you've used `str` as a variable earlier. So it's no longer the `str()` function, it's your variable. You shouldn't use built-in keywords as variable names.

Comment: type `print(str)` to see what you set it to.

Comment: @Barmar You are absolutely right! That solved the problem. Could you please tell me what you saw on the traceback which led you to it?

Comment: `'str' object is not callable`, so the problem is with something you're trying to call. The two things you're trying to call are `str` and `date.datetime.strptime`. It's more likely that you reassigned `str` than `date.datetime.strptime`.

Comment: It doesn't say that it's expecting a string. It says that it's trying to call a string, and it can't do that because strings aren't callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to do it like this:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date.today()
a = date.today().month
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime(a, "%M")
```

datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 5)

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(a, "%m")
```

datetime.datetime(1900, 5, 1, 0, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Your example works, except, that you have the date and datetime mixed up.

The import is `datetime`.  Within, you have two classes:

1. `date` for date related stuff
2. `datetime` for datetime related stuff

Here is a working example

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.date.today().month
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(str(a) , '%m')
datetime.datetime(1900, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```